# how can i plot the trust region around every step iteration?

Tags: c, plot, least-squares, gsl, model-fitting

[image]
[image]
[image]

The first image is what i would like to achieve and the second and third images are my values and the first attempt at the plot.

I would like to plot the trust region at every iteration. i am doing a nonlinear least-squares fitting and using the gsl library.

I did some changes to one of the source codes of the gsl library called "trust.c" and printed out the trust radius at every iteration.

i don't think scaling it is a good idea or that it would achieve the desired result of picture number 1 since the values vary largely.

Is there anyway else i can plot it?

fit_attempt 1 and fit_attempt 2 are the fit parameters since the fit is 2 dimensional.

my values vary largely so i cannot properly see the trust region radius even when i zoom in since they are very close together .
how can i fix this ?

Comment: Maybe you could [edit] your question to give us some more background and explain what you are trying to do. Do you have any code you can share with us?